# Impact of NA's when filtering Data Frames

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have a large data frame, which includes the following 2 fields and the number of rows shown (just 2 columns shown for simplicity):

```
> nrow(df)
[1] 3541393

> summary(df$ttlVisits)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.527   1.000 118.000 
> summary(df$AVGsessTOS)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
  1      27      30     115      72   21554  280146
```

**I would like to remove rows with AVGsessTOS > 1628**

```
> nrow(df[df$AVGsessTOS>=1628,])
[1] 300645
```

So, I run the following command, expecting 300,645 rows to be removed, but instead get 20,499:

> ## FILTER 1:
>
> df <- df[ df$AVGsessTOS < 1628, ]

The impact of the command on row counts and the 2 original columns:

```
> 3541393 - nrow(df)
[1] 20499

> summary(df$ttlVisits)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
   1.00    1.00    1.00    1.53    1.00  118.00  280146 
> summary(df$AVGsessTOS)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
    1.0    27.0    30.0   102.5    70.0  1627.5  280146
```

If I make a simple change to my filtering approach and use the **'which'** function, I get the results that I expect.

> ## FILTER 2:
>
> df <- df.bak # restore original data frame
>   df <- df[ which(df$AVGsessTOS < 1628), ]

And the impacts of the command:

```
> 3541393 - nrow(df)
[1] 300645

> summary(df$ttlVisits)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.526   1.000 118.000 
> summary(df$AVGsessTOS)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    1.0    27.0    30.0   102.5    70.0  1627.5
```

My interpretation of the above is that Filter #1 caused the expected 300,645 rows to get dropped BUT had a side effect of adding 280,146 "empty rows" due to the presence of NA's in df$AVGsessTOS. ( 300,645 - 280,146 = 20,499)

**Can someone confirm my interpretation of these results, and that this is the expected behavior of Filter #1?**

Maybe this will help someone else avoid getting bit by this as well. Thanks

> UPDATE: Replicating the issue with mtcars:

```
 data(mtcars) 
 set.seed(66)

> nrow(mtcars)
[1] 32
```

Looking at breakdown of the distribution of the 'carb' column is as-expected,  totaling 32:

```
 > table(mtcars$carb)
 1  2  3  4  6  8 
 7 10  3 10  1  1
```

Now set 3 carb values to NA (not entire row, just carb values) to create similar data to my dataset, to illustrate the problem:

```
 set.seed(66)
 mtcars[sample(1:nrow(mtcars), 3), ]$carb <- NA
```

Again, distribution of 'carb' column totals 29 is as expected, 3 less than the original after setting NA's:

```
> table(mtcars$carb)
 1  2  3  4  6  8 
 6 10  1 10  1  1
```

Now, drop the 6 rows shown above, with carb value of 1

```
> mtcars2 <- mtcars[mtcars$carb>=2,]
```

Confirm intended records were dropped:

```
> table(mtcars2$carb)
 2  3  4  6  8 
10  1 10  1  1
```

However, row count does NOT agree with above counts:

```
> nrow(mtcars2)
26
```

Inspecting the data shows 3 entire rows of NA values. **Where are these rows coming from?**

```
View(mtcars2)
( replicate to see output of 'view' )
```

Answer (score 2):

> My interpretation of the above is that Filter #1 caused the expected
>   300,645 rows to get dropped BUT had a side effect of adding 280,146
>   "empty rows" due to the presence of NA's in df$AVGsessTOS. ( 300,645 -
>   280,146 = 20,499)

On principle, subesetting *can't* expand your data frame. Have a look at the following example:

For the data set:

```
set.seed(123)
mtcars[sample(1:10, 3), ] <- NA
```

Filtering values according to criterion `mtcars[mtcars$carb > 2, ]` will result matching rows and `NAs`:

```
>> mtcars[mtcars$carb > 2, ]
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
NA                    NA  NA    NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
NA.1                  NA  NA    NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
NA.2                  NA  NA    NA  NA   NA    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
```

A more amusing explanation is provided via the [`fortunes`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fortunes/index.html) package:

```
fortunes::fortune(which = "is.na")
```

> JPM Miao: Why can't R understand if(num!=NA)?
>
> Peter Dalgaard: Because comparison with an unknown value yields an unknown result.
>
> David Winsemius: Anything else would violate the Second Law of Thermodynamics. We cannot have comparisons reducing entropy, now can we? Uncertainty cannot run uphill.
>
> *JPM Miao, Peter Dalgaard, and David Winsemius (on why is.na() is needed) R-help (May 2013)*

## Which

As for the role played by `which`, `which` [aims to return index of elements where logical value is `TRUE`](https://www.r-bloggers.com/which-function-in-r/) if you compare the results:

```
>> which(mtcars$carb > 2)
 [1]  2  7 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 24 29 30 31
>> mtcars$carb > 2
 [1]    NA  TRUE    NA    NA FALSE FALSE  TRUE    NA    NA    NA  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[14]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[27] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

`which` returns row indices for which condition is true whereas subsetting operations returns three values `NA`, `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

Comment: Bingo. Yes, you are correct. the problem was in my original expectation of 300,645.  nrow(df[df$AVGsessTOS>=1628,]) basically counted the 280,146 NA's as well.

Comment: Konrad, I'm going to temporarily retract my acceptance of the answer since I just noticed one open issue. While I understand and agree with your point about "on principal, subsetting can't expand your data", how do we explain the 280,146 NA's that got added to df$ttlVisits? (see Filter #1). I replicated the same issue using mtcars data and added it above. If you view the data in the last step, you will see the NA rows that were not in the original data.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like yes? I don't filter this way normally, usually I use `dplyr`.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x = sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE), y = sample(c(1, 4, NA), 100, replace = TRUE))
```

not using which:

```
> head(df[(df$y < 2),], 10)
      x  y
2     4  1
NA   NA NA
NA.1 NA NA
NA.2 NA NA
10    3  1
NA.3 NA NA
12    3  1
13    4  1
NA.4 NA NA
NA.5 NA NA
```

using which:

```
> head(df[which(df$y < 2),], 10)
   x y
2  4 1
10 3 1
12 3 1
13 4 1
16 5 1
22 4 1
23 4 1
24 5 1
27 3 1
28 3 1
```

I do encourage you to investigate your dataframes by using `head()`, or `View()` (in RStudio), or printing them somehow. It will help answer some of these questions about wondering what is happening!

Comment: Matt, in the case of this particular dataset head() and view() show exactly the same results for either of the filters. ( or the original data set).

Comment: really?! thats very interesting. I wonder why that's happening.